# Google Sheets, Referring to a cell range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Here's what I am trying to do.

In cell **C15**, I put the cell reference of another cell, e.g. ***`B2`***.

I another cell, cell **C16**, I want to check that IF the value in cell C15 contains the cell reference to any cell between **B5:D10**.

How could I do that please?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). That is an unusual request. Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Answer (score 1):

How to tell whether a given formula references a cell in a given range.

- Cell C15 references a single cell (such as,`=B2`).
- Is the cell referenced in cell C15 in a given range (such as, B5:D10)?

**What is the referenced cell?**

`=FORMULATEXT(C15)`

- this returns the formula as a string.
- such as,  "=B2"

**What is the row of the referenced cell**

`=value(REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(C15), "[0-9]+"))`

- `REGEXEXTRACT'` returns the Row number of the referenced cell as a string
- `VALUE` converts the string to a number.

**What is the column of the  the referenced cell?**

`=column(indirect(REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(C15), "[a-zA-Z]+")&"1"))`

- REGEXEXTRACT returns the column **letter** of the referenced cell
- `Column(Indirect(<<cell letter>>&"1"))` - converts the column letter to the column index

**Is the referenced cell in the given range: B5:D10**

Start by referencing the index values of the range.

- startColumn = 2, endColumn = 4, startRow = 5, endRow = 10

  **Is the row in the range?**

  If the row number is greater than or each to the "startRow" **AND** less than or equal to the "endRow" then the row in in the range.

  `=if(and(value(REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(C15), "[0-9]+"))>=5,value(REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(C15), "[0-9]+"))<=10),TRUE,)`

  **Is the column in the range?**

  If the column number is greater than or each to the "startColumn" **AND** less than or equal to the "endColumn" then the column in in the range.

  `=if(and(column(indirect(REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(C15), "[a-zA-Z]+")&"1"))>=2,column(indirect(REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(C15), "[a-zA-Z]+")&"1"))<=4),TRUE,)`

  **End Result**:

  If both formula are TRUE, then then the referenced cell is in the given range. Otherwise it is not in the given range.

**The complete formula**

`=if(and(if(and(value(REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(C15), "[0-9]+"))>=5,value(REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(C15), "[0-9]+"))<=10),TRUE,)=TRUE,if(and(column(indirect(REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(C15), "[a-zA-Z]+")&"1"))>=2,column(indirect(REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(C15), "[a-zA-Z]+")&"1"))<=4),TRUE,)=TRUE),TRUE,FALSE)`